# SPSS Ruby Reader

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spss

I need to be able to read a spss .sav file from my RoR application. Does anyone know a gem or ruby code that can understand the format and syntax of a spss .sav file?

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle C libraries in Ruby, check out the free i/o modules available from the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral).